# Node.js and OracleDB. SELECT object from DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, express, object

I have table in oracle db which has a object type column.

```
create or replace type background as Object
(user_name varchar(64),user_url varchar(128),background_thumb varchar(252),background_regular varchar(252));
```

In my node.js api i have a function which get all records from  table but i have a problem which that object :>

```
async function getAll(user) {
    user.user_id = parseInt(user.user_id, 10);
    const query = `SELECT
    BOARD_ID "board_id",
    NAME "name",
    t.background ...., ????
    IMPORTANT "important"
    from TO_DO_TABLE t
    WHERE USER_ID=:user_id`;

    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, user);
    return result.rows;
}

module.exports.getAll = getAll;
```

I would like  the downloaded  object to be a normal object not a string or a few properties.
Something like this

```
{ board_id: 171, name: 'aaa', background: {.......}, important: 0 },
```

I dont know how to get on with it. Of course  , i could get all properties separately in SELECT and then create an object but is any better way?

EDIT

When i run something like that

```
async function getAll(user) {
    user.user_id = parseInt(user.user_id, 10);
    const query = `SELECT
    BOARD_ID "board_id",
    NAME "name",
    t.background "background" , 
    IMPORTANT "important"
    from TO_DO_TABLE t
    WHERE USER_ID=:user_id`;

    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, user);
    return result.rows;
}

module.exports.getAll = getAll;
```

I have this error `Error: DPI-1010: not connected`

When i run something like that when i SELECT object properites separately

```
async function getAll(user) {
    user.user_id = parseInt(user.user_id, 10);
    const query = `SELECT
    BOARD_ID "board_id",
    NAME "name",
    t.background.user_name "user_name" , 
    t.background.background_thumb "thumb" , 
    IMPORTANT "important"
    from TO_DO_TABLE t
    WHERE USER_ID=:user_id`;

    const result = await database.simpleExecute(query, user);
    return result.rows;
}

module.exports.getAll = getAll;
```

It's good but as I wrote earlier i would like to SELECT all background object as object :>

```
    {
        "board_id": 171,
        "name": "aaa",
        "user_name": "aaa",
        "thumb": "adadad",
        "important": 0
    },
```

Comment: what is returned as of now? it would help to guide you

Comment: Check the node-oracledb [manual](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html) and [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) for how to work with objects.  If you still have problems, update your question with the SQL to create the objects and a [runnable example](http://sscce.org/).  I suspect your 'simpleExecute()' is closing the connection before you've accessed the object - so try keeping the connection open longer.

Comment: Hi David, did you still need help with this? If so, what version of the database are you using?